# rendered input text box does not respond to arrow keys

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

```
{ 
    headerName: "Total", 
    field: "total", 
    cellRenderer: (params) => {
         var box = document.createElement("input");
         box.type = "text";
         box.value = "inverse";
         return box;
    }
}
```

Above code will render an input box but the problem is when I press arrow keys inside the input field , the cursor is not moving within the input box,(I have to use my mouse click to go 2nd position in the input box). However space and backspace are working though. Is this an issue with ag-grid? Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the grid will treat the arrow keys and enter (as well as escape) keys that stop editing a given cell when using custom editors.

You can override this by listening to key events and acting on them:

`MoodEditor.prototype.onKeyDown = function (event) {
    var key = event.which || event.keyCode;
    if (key == 37 ||  // left
        key == 39) {  // right
        this.toggleMood();
        event.stopPropagation();
    }
};`

See https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-editor/exampleEditorComponent.html for a working example of this (the mood column)

Comment: I was talking about cellrenderer and your solution is on celleditor? can you please check the same

Comment: If you're going to provide input then an editor is more appropriate - you could try do the same thing with a renderer, but it would involve more work. Do you just want to display the cell value, or edit it with the input?

Comment: I have to perform edit operations, but is there a solution to do it for cellrenderer? please do let me know

Comment: Thank you very much :) It helps a lot.